# HttpContext.Current is null in WCF Data Service hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, httpcontext

I created a WCF Data Service inside a Windows Service and tried to access the HttpContext.

I added this to my config file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />   
 </system.serviceModel>
```

However, when I try to access it, it is null.

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
      base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);   
      HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
      File.AppendAllText(@"c:\Temp\ERROR.log",
      httpContext != null
       ?"HTTPCONTEXT IS NOT NULL"
       :"HTTPCONTEXT IS NULL");
    }
```

What else should I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I'm afraid so:

> The disabled ASP.NET HTTP features are:
>
> HttpContext.Current: This is always null in this mode. For ASMX services, this is a ThreadStatic property that is stored in the Thread Local Store (TLS). WCF provides a counterpart to this feature: OperationContext.Current.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx

Comment: Correct - if you're hosting your WCF service inside a Windows service, there's obviously no ASP.NET components and thus no `HttpContext` involved .... WCF is **NOT** ASP.NET - it's quite a different technology

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I'm still looking for some information about how to use gzip on the outgoing stream. HttpContext would have been good...