# Session support in self-hosted WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services

I created a self-hosted WCF data service and as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425649/httpcontext-current-is-null-in-wcf-data-service-hosted-in-windows-service), I discovered that it does not support the ASP.Net context (HttpContext.Current is null).

Am I correct if I suppose that session handling is also *not available* in a self-hosted data service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Session handling is not available in self-hosted WCF Data Services** as it utilizies the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class which relies on ASP.Net context and it is *[always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425649/httpcontext-current-is-null-in-wcf-data-service-hosted-in-windows-service)* in Data Services. 
So you have to implement a custom solution to imitate session handling in WCF Data Services.

Answer (score 1):

In the self hosted service, you should be able to Use the SessionMode enumeration with the `ServiceContractAttribute.SessionMode` property to require, allow, or prohibit bindings to use sessions between endpoints that connect to or support the service contract.
For example, if the `SessionMode` property is set to `SessionMode.Allowed` and the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode` property is set to `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`, a client can use a binding that supports reliable sessions to make repeated calls to the same service object.  If your service supports sessions, you can then use the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode' property to specify the relationship between instances of your service contract implementation and the channel session.

The following links provide good reference information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.sessionmode.aspx

Regards,

Comment: Does it apply to WCF Data Services or only to regular WCF services?

Comment: I have not configured a service that way myself, but the following exchange seems to confirm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109728/how-to-have-application-use-different-databases-via-wcf-dataservice

Comment: It also seems a regular WCF service with contracts. In WCF Data Services there are no contracts of operation, there are only web addresses that provide data in JSON (or Atom) format using REST calls. Check it, it is very good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794(v=vs.110).aspx